# Access parent object in JavaScript from iFrame/Window

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent-child

How do I access a global object or array defined in a parent window in the child window.

```
<script>
    var events_data;
    function function_to_fill_events_data () {
      .
      .
      .
    }
</script>

<div>
    <div><iframe src="mini.php" width:100%; height: 100%;" scrolling="no"></iframe> </div>
</div>
```

When I am in the mini document I'd like to be able to access the events_data variable in a javascript function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Option 1**

Your title mentions a child window. If you have a child window, and not an iframe, use this:

```
window.opener.events_data
```

Check out [`window.opener` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener).

**Option 2**

Your code indicates that you're using an iframe. From an iframe, simply use `parent`:

```
parent.events_data;
```

Check out [`window.parent` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent).

---

`window.opener` - Returns a reference to the window that opened this current window.

`window.parent` - When a window is loaded in an , , or , its parent is the window with the element embedding the window.

Comment: And what about permission deniel ? If browser doesn't allow to access parent properties from iframe ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this happens when the contents of iframe is loaded from another domain

Comment: @Malgin, you're correct. Cross domain scripting is a huge security risk and is therefore not allowed. You can tell that the OP is not attempting to do that because the `src` attribute of his iframe is using a relative path.

Comment: @JamesHill All that is true, but if this is required ? Here's my question and the way I'm going to do that in my app ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788328/access-parent-window-from-iframe-cross-domain))

Comment: @Malgin, ask these questions in your thread, not in the comments of this question.