# Javascript frame killer with exceptions

Tags: javascript, frame

I'm using that code to kill frames using my page:

```
if(self == top) {
       document.documentElement.style.display = 'block'; 
    } else {
            top.location = self.location;
    };
```

But I want add some exception for one domain and add another condition:

```
if(self == top) {
       document.documentElement.style.display = 'block'; 
    } else {
        if (window.location.host != "www.linuxportal.pl") {
            top.location = self.location;
        };
    };
```

But it won't work. Script kills every frame, even from www.linuxportal.pl. How to make script to kill every frame but leave frame in www.linuxportal.pl only?

Comment: Shouldn't your `if` condition be `window.top.location.host !== '...'` ?

Comment: No, it wont work. In Chrome console I got "Uncaught SecurityError".

Comment: Ahh cross-domain, of course it wont work.

Comment: See [Access parent window from iframe (cross-domain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788328/access-parent-window-from-iframe-cross-domain)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with `document.referrer`

```
if(self == top) {
       document.documentElement.style.display = 'block'; 
    } 
else {
    if (document.referrer.indexOf("www.linuxportal.pl") >= 0 ) {
        document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        top.location = self.location;
    }
};
```