# How can I get document from iframe from different origin?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to get document from iframe using

```
document.getElementById('product-page').contentWindow.document
```

but I keep getting this error below, is there any way i can avoid the error?

> VM1342:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "URL" from
>   accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at :1:54

Comment: This is CROS error, the url used in iframe might be in other domain as your parent page, check more on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access parent window from iframe (cross-domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788328/access-parent-window-from-iframe-cross-domain)

Answer (score 1):

maybe its cannot because diffrent origin http

if diffrent hostname and port each iframe will be get CORS

For an explanation of CORS, please see this answer from programmers: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/253043/139479

Answer (score 1):

This is a restriction due to Same Origin Security Policy,
If the iframe is from a different domain/port/protocol, you cannot access it via javascript.

Origin is considered different if at least one of the following parts of the address is not the same as your calling url:

```
<protocol>://<hostname>:<port>/path/to/page.html
```

But there is a way if you own both the websites you're trying to access,

Refer this answer for more info : 
[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)